# Measuring RTT and retrieve time between a sensor and a platform

Tags: python, sensors, roundtrip

Suppose we have a platform for receiving data from a sensor. We show the measuring time for sending a data value from a sensor to the platform with TR (retrieve time). All I want is what code can be used to calculate TR and also RTT (round trip time) in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention specifics such latency threshold and protocol. I think your best bet is to setup a client/server ping/pong server.

Here is some simple zeromq python code ([Request/Reply pattern](https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/client_server.html)) to test latency (single trip and round trip)

server.py

```
import zmq,time,sys

ctx =zmq.Context()
socket = ctx.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind('tcp://*:9999')

while True:
    msg = socket.recv()
    print "client->server msg took",time.time()-float(msg)
    socket.send(msg)
```

client.py

```
import zmq,time,sys                                                                                                                        

ctx =zmq.Context()                                                                                                                         
socket = ctx.socket(zmq.REQ)                                                                                                               
socket.connect('tcp://localhost:9999')                                                                                                     
for i in xrange(10):                                                                                                                       
    socket.send(str(time.time()))                                                                                                          
    msg = socket.recv()                                                                                                                    
    print "message id",i,"RT",time.time()-float(msg)
```

You can run both of them the same time to give you latency stats. 
Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your help. In fact the platform is an IOT platform like Thingspeak or Xively that receive the messages from sensors via API under http or mqtt requests. As you know sensors send data to the platform (after the configuration) continuously. since average the RTT has much importance to evaluate a platform.

Comment: Also i have full code for transferring  data  to platform and only im looking for how i should calculate RTT for every message which is send.